# drupal 6: using ahah for forms with markup types

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, ahah

```
function MyModule_menu() {
  $items['blah'] = array(
    'title' = 'blah',
    'page callback' => 'blah_page',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );
  $items['clickPath'] = array(
    'title' => 'A title',
    'page callback' => 'clickPath_page',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function blah_page() {
  $output = drupal_get_form(MyModule_form);
  return $output;
}
function clickPath_page() {
  return ('you clicked me!');
}

function MyModule_form($form,&$form_state) {
  $output = '<div id="clickDiv">Click me</div>';

  $form['blah'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#value' => $output,
    '#ahah' => array(
      'event' => 'click',
      'path' => 'clickPath',
      'wrapper' => 'clickDiv',
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Why won't the above work?  Is it not possible to use ahah and events on form types of 'markup'?  Do I have to use my own custom javascript?

You can stop reading here!  I would like to end my sentences and question here, but stackoverflow is forcing me to input a minimum amount of characters.  Apologies in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#ahah) under "Special Elements" you can see that the `#ahah` attribute is not supported for the `markup` form type.

So I'm afraid you will have to roll your own JS in this case, or convert the `markup` element into a normal form element (which it doesn't look like will work for your purposes).

Comment: Bummerz!  Thanks for finding the source for this.